# Converting a string to an array in Lua

Tags: lua, luajit

Why does this syntax work:

```
if ({A=1,B=1,C=1})["A"]  then print("hello") end
```

while this does not:

```
local m = {string.sub(string.gsub("A,B,C,", ",", "=1,"),1,-2)}

if (m)["A"]  then print("hello") end
```

???

I think it's because a string is not an array, but how can I convert a string (`"a,b,c"`) to an array (`{a=1,b=1,c=1}`)?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: As has already been mentioned, you are not allowed to vandalize your old questions by replacing them with nonsense. You are also not allowed to *completely change* your question if doing so will invalidate existing answers. Since you would not stop doing this, this question has been locked to prevent further edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
local m = {string.sub(string.gsub("A,B,C,", ",", "=1,"),1,-2)}
```

is equivalent to this

```
local v = string.sub(string.gsub("A,B,C,", ",", "=1,"),1,-2)
local m = {v}
```

which, I hope you agree, would clearly not have the behavior of assigning multiple values in the `m` table.

To "parse" simple `a=1,b=1,c=1` type strings into a table the second example of [`string.gmatch`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch) from the manual is helpful:

> The next example collects all pairs key=value from the given string into a table:
>
> ```
> t = {}
> s = "from=world, to=Lua"
> for k, v in string.gmatch(s, "(%w+)=(%w+)") do
>   t[k] = v
> end
> ```

Comment: Note: the two samples are not equivalent in general; the second one truncates the result of `string.sub` to one value, while the first sample will store all return values in the array.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo While true `string.sub` only ever returns one value.